# How to access deeply nested array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I have to access data from an API that is similar to:

```
{
 "name": "nameofevent",
 "speakers": [
   {
     "name": "speakerName"
   }
 ]
}
```

I am not sure how to access the speakerName inside speakers. Below is what I have, but I don't think I can do it that way because the speaker name has the same variable name as name. How would I access the speakerName?

```
{publicEvents.map((event) => {
    const { name, speakers: [{name}]} = event;
    return (
        <EventsCard
            eventName={name}
            speakerName={name}
        />
    ); 
})}
```

Comment: I guess there might be more than one speaker at any given event, which is probably why "speakers" is an array.  Your code should handle multiple speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign different variable names when destructuring.

```
{publicEvents.map((event) => {
    const { name: eventName, speakers: [{name: speakerName}]} = event;
    return (
           <EventsCard
                 eventName={eventName}
                 speakerName={speakerName}
           />
      ); 
    })}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As James said, it is an array so you need to specify that item in the array, since it is possible to have multiple speakers. Something like this could be used to select the first item:

```
speakers[0].name
```

Comment: This is correct but does not answer the question. The poster was specifically asking about a fairly advanced usage of object/array destructuring (commonly used in React) if you pay attention to the code sample and tags.